# Error while running CsipSample code.

Tags: sip, pjsip, csip-simple

I downloaded Csipsample from google code and trying to work on that.I built the app based on the instructions given in https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild

while running the app on my mobile it is giving

```
"can't load native library. cpu arch invalid for this build"
```

Even when i try to run it on Emulator also it is giving the same error.In some forum i found there might be problem with .so files. Even i tried that one also but still its not working.

The same problem i found here also :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/csipsimple-dev/uxkRx1vmzNk

Can anyone please give a solution for this ?

Comment: found a solution ?!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename your `Lib` folder with `Libs`